# Override Drupal view field formatting?

Tags: drupal-7, view

I have a content type called "thing". A thing can have a "size", that is either "small", "medium" or "large". For a specific view, I want to change this output to rather say: "100 Square Meters" for small, "200 Square Meters" for medium and "300 Square Meters" for large.

What is the most elegant solution to do this? I don't want any weird if and else logic in my view, or worse yet, use Views PHP. Isn't there any easy way to add a field like this with multiple values, but output it in a certain way for a specific view?

**UPDATE**

I was considering using [this](https://www.drupal.org/project/formatter_field).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that in many ways , the most simple way is to override the template field for that field
 [Check out this tutorial](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/views-templates/)

One more way using [custom_formatters module](https://www.drupal.org/project/custom_formatters) which let you create custom format using token , which should be simple for you

If you will do this one time only, better to do with the first way, no need to install module you will use it only for one time

Comment: The first tutorial doesn't really show how to override a specific field. It seems more relevant if you want to simply override the them files. Is there no way to have a view template for a SPECIFIC field?

Comment: In the view interface just click on information - 3rd column - and you will see list of all template files for fields also , copy the one you want  to your theme and theme it , you will have variable called $row which contain all the data you need [See this also](https://www.drupal.org/node/2331589)